# similar code logic, two different answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

why does the output of these two functions give different outputs when the logic or idea is the same and they are working with the same string?

```
def solution(inputString):
    a = ""
    b = a[::-1]
    if a == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False



print(solution("az"))

def ans(something):
    if something == reversed(something):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
ans('az')
```

Comment: It seems your second function is _printing_ `True`, while the first function is _returning_ it as a value. If you want both to do the same thing, make the second return True instead of printing it. EDIT : Also your first function doesn't even use its input...

Comment: On both functions, you can replace the `if` by just returning the value of your statement: `return something == reversed(something)`

Comment: `reversed` is a type, so `something == reversed(something)` will never be true when `something` is a `str` value.

Comment: Maybe because `solution` ignores its input parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is I think because you are not using your `inputString` parameter in the function `solution()`. This may be closer to what you want:

```
def solution(inputString):
    a = inputString
    b = a[::-1]
    if a == b:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the logic or idea is the same

No, the `solution` and `ans` functions have different logic.

---

`solution` uses the [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python) of reversing a string, thats fine

---

However, the second function uses [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function, which does:

> `reversed(seq)`
>
> Return a reverse iterator. `seq` must be an object which has a `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol ...

It does not return the reversed string as you'd probably expected.

To put that in perspective, the following code returns `False`:

```py
print("oof" == reversed("foo"))
```

Because the return value of `reversed("foo")` is an <reversed object> and not the reversed String.